# swift floor function gives wrong result

Tags: ios, swift, floor

I spent hours trying to find the problem but I didn't find it.

Here is the problem :

```
let n = 4.99/Float(1)
print("n : \(n)")
let n1 = Float(10000)*n
print("n1 : \(n1)")
let n2 = floor(n1)
print("n2 : \(n2)")
let n3 = Int(n1)
print("n3 : \(n3)")
```

The result in the console is :

```
n : 4.99
n1 : 49900.0
n2 : 49899.0
n3 : 49899.0
```

My question is why n2 and n3 are equal to 49899. It should be equal to 49900.0

I tried to write

```
let n2 = floor(49900.0)
```

and it works perfectly. It shows me 49900.0. It's what I want.

I really don't know what I'm not doing good.

Comment: Add `print(String(format: "%.9f", n))` and you will see the issue.

Comment: And using `Double` instead of `Float` fixes this specific issue.

Comment: Using `Double` fixes it for this example, but there will be others where it will fail.

Comment: Why is Float displaying it like this ?

Comment: In short, floating point numbers are approximations.  The internal representation is binary, so values like `0.1` do not have an exact representation.  `Float` uses 32-bits to represent a number, and `Double` uses 64 bits.  So `Double` does a better job, but it is still an approximation.  `4.99` as a `Float` is stored as `4.9899997711181640625`, so it is slightly less than you expect.  When you multiply by `10000`, it becomes `49899.99609375` and `floor` drops the fraction leaving `49899`.  For `Double` `4.99` is represented as `4.99000000000000021316282072803` so it is larger than `4.99`.

Comment: `Double` doesn't eliminate the problem.  You will still find examples where it doesn't perform as you expect.